# The number of residue classes $[a]$ mod n such that $[a]^{n-1} = [1]$

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

Let $n =p^\alpha$ where p is a prime.

I'm trying to follow a longer proof for the Miller-Rabin Test that uses the fact that there are $p-1=\gcd(\phi(n),n-1)$ residue classes such that $[a]^{n-1} = [1]$.

I can show that $p-1=\gcd(\phi(n),n-1)$, but cannot see why there are $p-1$ choices for $[a]$.

Edit: $\phi(n)$ is referring to Euler's function

Comment: Does $\phi (n)$ denote Euler's phi function?

Comment: yes, edited for clarity

Comment: If $p>2$, then $\Bbb{Z}_{p^\alpha}$ is known to be cyclic of order $\phi(p^\alpha)$. In a cyclic group of order $m$ the equation $x^\ell=1$ has $d=\gcd(\ell, m)$ solutions. This is covered in all textbooks. If $g$ is a generator, then $x=g^j$ is a solution of $x^\ell=1$ if and only if $m\mid \ell j$ if and only if $j$ is a multiple of $m/d$ etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's an elementary result that

> if $G$ is a finite **cyclic** group and $k$ is an integer, then the subset $G_k := \{g^k|g \in G\}$ of $k$th powers of elements of $G$ forms a subgroup of order $\text{gcd}(\#G, k)$.

*Proof.* Indeed, if $G=\langle a \rangle$, then $G_k = \langle a^k \rangle$ and so $$\#G_k = \text{ord}_G(a^k) = \text{gcd}(\text{ord}_G(a), k) = \text{gcd}(\#G,k). \quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\Box$$

---

Now, for your particular problem, take $k = n - 1$ and $G = \mathbb Z_n^*$, the multiplicative group of integers modulo $n = p^\alpha$. Note that $\#G = \phi(n)$ and moreover, $G$ is cyclic if $p$ is an odd prime. Conclude.